# difficulty using AttributeSet.getAttributeIntValue()

Tags: android

My app needs the height and width of the extended ImageView. I thought this should work:

```
package my.android.test;

public class TestImageView extends ImageView
{
    private int mWidth=0;
    private int mHeight=0;

    public TestImageView(Context context, AttributeSet as)
    {
        super(context, as);
        final String xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
        mWidth = as.getAttributeIntValue(xmlns, "layout_width", 0);
        mHeight = as.getAttributeIntValue(xmlns, "layout_height", 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. 0 is returned by getAttributeIntValue() eventhough the layout_height is defined in the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:fillViewport="true"
          android:background="#fffcb95a"

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="6dip"

        <my.android.test.TestImageView
                    android:id="@+id/TestImageViewID" 
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="100dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </RelativeLayout

</FrameLayout

</LinearLayout
</ScrollView
```

what to do ?

Comment: note to self: good example code to step through the AttribSet ... http://codinggeek.org/2011/03/07/android-configure-custom-views-via-xml/

Comment: Thank you for the link. [This](https://codinggeekorg.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/android-configure-custom-views-via-xml/) is the right currently working one, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`.

Comment: I tried that from the constructor, after the call to super(), getWidth() and getHeight() return 0. Would have been nice though if it were that easy (it should be that easy). EDIT... unless using it in the constructor is too soon ?

Comment: Well at that point it hasn't been added to a layout so it is 0. If you need it to draw or something you should get it in the onDraw method using getWidth() and getHeight(). Also it's not good to store it either since it might not be static.

Comment: it does get a value from within onDraw(). This value is larger than I specified in the Layout XML - is that because of the display density ? getWidth() and getHeight() both return 150.

Comment: getWidth() and getHeight() return pixels, and in your layout you are setting them with dip, so yeah the display affects it.

Answer (score 3):

Note an explanation for why the original attempt doesn't work -- layout_width and layout_height are not actually holding integers, they are holding dimensions.  You need to retrieve these via Context/Theme.obtainStyledAttributes, so you can get them as a TypedValue that can be converted to pixels.